# what's wrong in this code that i'm getting: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, numpy

```
y_pred = model.predict(X_val)

classes=np.argmax(y_pred,axis=1)
acc_test = 0

for i in range(X_val.shape[0]):

    if(y_pred[i] == y_val[i]):
        acc_test= acc_test+1

print("Accuracy test : "  , acc_test/X_val.shape[0]*100)
```

Comment: Did you check the shapes of `y_pred` and `y_val` objects? If these objects are multidimensional objects, then you have to specify the other-dimensional indices. Print the shapes of both values before making a comparison since this error says that you are comparing objects, not values!

Comment: Please specify in which instruction this error occurs. And provide a sample of source data, in **text** form (not picture), for which you got this error.

Comment: For a given `i` what is `(y_pred[i] == y_val[i])`?